# RPM spec file build error field must be present

Tags: linux, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

Can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong here.

Currently, trying to build an rpm for the following redis postgres foreign data wrapper.

- Git link for repo: https://github.com/nahanni/rw_redis_fdw.git
- Link for tar file: https://github.com/nahanni/rw_redis_fdw/archive/v0.7.tar.gz

The spec file is located in `/rpmbuild/SPECS` and the tar file is located in `/rpmbuild/SOURCES`.

When I run `rpmbuild -ba redis_fdw.spec` from the `/rpmbuild/SPECS` directory, I get the following error:

```
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.78237
+ umask 022
+ cd /root/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ LANG=C
+ export LANG
+ unset DISPLAY
+ cd /root/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ rm -rf redis_fdw-0.7
+ /bin/mkdir -p redis_fdw-0.7
+ cd redis_fdw-0.7
+ /usr/bin/gzip -dc /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/rw_redis_fdw-0.7.tar.gz
+ tar -xf -
+ STATUS=0
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
++ /usr/bin/id -u
+ '[' 0 = 0 ']'
+ /bin/chown -Rhf root .
++ /usr/bin/id -u
+ '[' 0 = 0 ']'
+ /bin/chgrp -Rhf root .
+ /bin/chmod -Rf a+rX,u+w,g-w,o-w .
+ exit 0
Executing(%install): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.78237
+ umask 022
+ cd /root/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ cd redis_fdw-0.7
+ LANG=C
+ export LANG
+ unset DISPLAY
+ rm -rf /var/tmp/redis_fdw94-0.7.0
+ mkdir /var/tmp/redis_fdw94-0.7.0
+ PATH=/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
+ make install DESTDIR=/var/tmp/redis_fdw94-0.7.0
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.78237 (%install)


RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.78237 (%install)
```

**redis_fdw.spec** file

```
#@IgnoreInspection BashAddShebang
%global redis_fdw_major 0
%global redis_fdw_minor 7
%global redis_fdw_build 0
%global postgresql_major 9
%global postgresql_minor 4
%global postgresql_build 15
%global redis_fdw_tag_ver v%{redis_fdw_major}.%{redis_fdw_minor}
%global redis_fdw_ver %{redis_fdw_major}.%{redis_fdw_minor}.%{redis_fdw_build}
%global redis_fdw_ver_short %{redis_fdw_major}.%{redis_fdw_minor}
%global postgresql_ver %{postgresql_major}.%{postgresql_minor}.%{postgresql_build}
%global postgresql_ver_short %{postgresql_major}.%{postgresql_minor}
%global postgresql_ver_major %{postgresql_major}%{postgresql_minor}
%global name redis_fdw%{postgresql_ver_major}
%global repo_name redis_fdw-%{redis_fdw_ver_short}

Summary: Redis FDW
Name: %{name}
Version: %{redis_fdw_ver}
Release: 1.1tl%{?dist}
License: Commercial
Group: Application/Phillip

Source0: rw_redis_fdw-%{redis_fdw_ver_short}.tar.gz

Provides: %{name} = %{pkg_ver}-%{pkg_rel}
BuildRoot: %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}
BuildRequires: hiredis
BuildRequires: postgresql%{postgresql_ver_major}-devel = %{postgresql_ver}
Requires: postgresql%{postgresql_ver_major}-server = %{postgresql_ver}

%description
Redis Foreign Data Wrapper for PostgreSQL

%prep
%setup -q -n %{repo_name}

%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
mkdir ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}
PATH=/usr/pgsql-%{postgresql_ver_short}/bin:$PATH make install DESTDIR=${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}

%clean
rm -rf ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}

%files
%attr(664, postgres, postgres) /usr/pgsql-%{postgresql_ver_short}/share/extension/%{base_name}.control
%attr(664, postgres, postgres) /usr/pgsql-%{postgresql_ver_short}/share/extension/%{base_name}--*
%attr(664, postgres, postgres) /usr/pgsql-%{postgresql_ver_short}/lib/%{base_name}.so


%changelog
* Mon Jan 08 2018 Phillip Phillip <phillip@phillip.com> 0.7.0
- initial RPM
```

Comment: The spec file contains `CRLF` line endings instead of `LF`. Run `dos2unix redis_fdw.spec` to remove all the `CR`.

Comment: thanks! However, I'm still getting an error. I updated the error I'm receiving in the above description.

Comment: The new error seems that the files in the tar isn't under a directory `redis_fdw-0.7`. Change this line `%setup -q -n %{repo_name}` to `%setup -q -c -n %{repo_name}`.

Comment: I checked the contents of the tar file. The directory is different than what you have in `%setup -q -n %{repo_name}`. Change it to `%setup -q -n rw_%{repo_name}` instead.

Comment: hmmm, now I'm getting a `No rule to make target 'install'` error. I updated the error I'm receiving in the above desciption. I'm still trying to determine what the exact error is. I'm thinking it may have something to do with my variable `repo_name`.